# When to save an instance in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

What are the guidelines to save the instance in grails?

I am doing something like this:

```
def colorInstance = Color.findOrSaveByName(colorname)
if (colorInstance.startsWith("R")) {
   colorInstance.isRColor = true;
}
```

Should I be calling `colorInstance.save()` in the if block or not? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save an instance explicitly (just as per your example) whenever your flow requires it.

Consider that `at the end of a request cycle, when a GORM session is flushed, a dirty check operation is performed. Objects that are binded to the session are compared against their original values and if changes are detected, they are persisted`.

From http://www.redwindsw.com/blog/2014-01-15-moving-from-rails-to-grails-differences-and-similarities, read the paragraph about **The Hibernate Session**.

Answer (score 0):

in grails 2.3.4 `colorInstance .save flush:true`

in grails 2.2.2 `colorInstance.save(flush:true)`

Comment: using parathenses like that is not related with version of Grails, and they both work the same, anyway it doesn't really answer the question